# Audio streaming library for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, media-player, audio-streaming, audio-player

I'm working on audio streaming from URLs, so currently I'm just playing audio via `AVAudioPlayer` but now I want to show  it visually too.

I searched on CocoaControls but couldn't find any good library that can stream/play audios while showing the player controls as well as seek bar and stuff.

anything similar to this (I just need Play/Pause and Stop buttons though)
[image]

Can you please suggest any good library?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=music go through this link .

Comment: Thanks, I also just found this amazing library (as it looks though) [AFSoundManager](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/afsoundmanager), for anyone having similar query as mine!

Comment: you can use streamKit get it from : https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit

Comment: AFSoundManager not handle interruption

Comment: @JanakThakkar Can you suggest a better alternative?